# Get n last modified objects from an Amazon S3 bucket prefix using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filter, boto3, server-side

I need to get the list of object keys sorted by their last modified timestamp from S3 prefix. Since there is a lot of objects present, and I know I am interested in certain certain number of objects that have been recently modified, what would be the way to do that in `boto3`?

Sorting all the objects on the client side as I currently do takes very long time:

```
def get_last_modified(obj):
    return int(obj.last_modified.strftime("%s"))

def process(prefix):
    input_bucket = boto3.resource("s3").Bucket("my-test-bucket")
    objects = list(input_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix))
    sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)
```

Comment: You could use s3api with `list-objects-v2` and `--query ...` if you don't have too many objects this can work nicely. Otherwise, you cou keep track of object updates with a Lambda function and maintain a sorted list in sone store like DynamoDB

Comment: If you can tolerate the results being a few hours old then look at S3 Inventory reports.

Answer (score 2):

I have been searching around for a filtering option within `boto3` however it seems it is not available out of the box. All solutions suggest pulling all files and then working with the result. The below is conditional on the naming convention of your files, but it does the trick.

Here is something that works for me and it seems might be relevant here too: You mention you are interested in file recently modified and that you have that timestamp in the prefix of the filename

In my case the files are named `FOLDER/PREFIX_<TIMESTAMP>.json`, with TIMESTAMP being the time of the generation of the file. You can use `list_objects_v2` with `StartAfter` which filters ascending by name of file.

So my bucket looks like so:

```
FOLDER/PREFIX_1662634638.json.zip
FOLDER/PREFIX_1662634774.json.zip
FOLDER/PREFIX_1662634882.json.zip
```

In my case I can basically get files from the last X seconds and then filter clint-side if needed.

To get all files from the last hour, do the following (given file structure example above):

```py
import boto3
import datetime

s3 = boto3.client('s3', 
      aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
      aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)

last_hour = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60*60)
last_hour_ts = int(last_hour.timestamp())

s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket = 'MY_BUCKET',
    Prefix = 'FOLDER/PREFIX', 
    StartAfter = f'FOLDER/PREFIX_{last_hour_ts}')
```

Hope that helps!